# Using ajax response in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, ajax, response

I have an ajax call returning a response for heatmap data.

The problem I'm having is that to update the heatmap with the new data, I have to call a function using the data from the ajax response.

Here is the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var interval = setInterval(function() {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "update_1.php",
data: {},
cache: false,
success: function(html){
    var response = eval("(" + html + ')');
    $('#checker').html(html);
if(response.success)
    {
heatmap.store.setDataSet(response);
    }
}
}); }, 10000);

</script>
```

and an example of the return from the ajax call to be called by setDataSet() :

```
{max:30, data:[{ x: 480, y: 500, count: 27.00 },{ x: 250, y: 280, count: 26.00 },{ x: 480, y: 330, count: 21.00 },]}
```

I have tried to use eval() to make it useable but it isn't working.

IS there anything I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, the setDataSet isn't updating the heatmap with the new data.

Comment: dataType: "json", And use: response.max. Or resp = $.parseJSON(response);

Comment: dataType: "json" just stops the ajax call happening all together

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX call is returning JSON. To "make it useable", you need to convert it into a javascript object. There are several ways to do it, I'd say that the easiest is to use [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead of $.ajax.

[Updates]

- as RobH said in the comments, make sure your JSON format is valid
- if(response.success) doesn't make sense, I'd suggest that you simply remove it

Comment: @Jimbob it will be failing because your JSON is invalid.

Comment: +1 to RobH comment, your returned data has an unusual format. For example, I would expect max, data, x, y, count to be under quotes, which would be a standard format (JSON).

Comment: the if(response.success) is also dubious. What's your intent here?

Comment: To be honest I copied the response.success from someone who was using eval(). Clearly the wrong thing to do. I'm a bit of a newcomer at json

Comment: just try to remove the if statement, you have already validated that your response is successful. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I have removed it now because as you say it was pointless. It looks like now the `setDataSet` is failing so will contact the guy who wrote it

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do would be to use:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update_1.php",
        data: {},
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            heatmap.store.setDataSet(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, error){
            console.log(xhr); 
            console.log(error);
        }
    }); 
}, 10000);
```

But your JSON will need to be valid or it will fail silently.

You need to wrap the keys in quotes: check here: http://jsonlint.com

e.g.
`{ "max": 30, "data":[{ "x": 480, "y": 500, "count": 27.00 },{ "x": 250, "y": 280, "count": 26.00 },{ "x": 480, "y": 330, "count": 21.00 }]}`

Comment: @Jimbob - you need to see if the AJAX call is failing or whether your `heatmap.store.setDataSet()` is at fault. Add a failure callback to the AJAX call.

Comment: It seems the setDataSet() is at fault because the ajax isn't failing

Comment: @Jimbob glad the AJAX is working but I'm afraid i don't know anything about this 'heatmap' :(

Comment: Thanks for your help @RobH and everyone else. The heatmap I am using i s http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/  I contacted him and asked whether I could update using ajax and he said to call `heatmap.store.setDataSet(data);` every 10 seconds so I have been using ajax to renew the data....... I'll have to re-contact him

Comment: @Jimbob - just looked on his repo and it definitely looks like this should work as there is a call internally to clear the map the redraw with the new data. You have created the heatmap first right?